# Difference in account and conatct

Tags: salesforce

I have doubt on salesforce objects. Actually what is the difference between a contact with an account and a contact without an account? In what cases we use this? Please Explain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Contact A contact, which is an individual associated with an Account.

Account An individual account, which is an organization involved with your business (such as customers, competitors, and partners).

It is possible to create a contact without an account; however, this contact will be a private contact, hidden from all users except the ones with Modify All Data or Modify All [on Contacts]. The way to remove the restriction on 'requiring' an account when creating a contact is to remove the 'required' property from the Contact page layout, thereby giving me the ability to create a contact without an Account. There is also a feature called Business to Consumer or B2C that provides for person accounts which is a fusion of the account and contact record. This person account would give the ability to reference a supplier object through a lookup relationship, but the same rules apply, it can't be a master-detail relationship to reinforce security or handle clean up when deleting the supplier record.

Comment: In what cases do we create a contact without an account? @Android_Rocks